# mongoengine - dynamically generating Q()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is there a way to dynamically generate a Q() other than using eval().

Current method with eval():

q = eval("Q(" + q_arg + mode + "=args[arg])")

Where mode is "_*in" or "*_nin".

This works, just trying to do it without eval()

Answer (score 3):

`Q` objects, like any python class can just take `kwargs` - which can be a dictionary, so you can just build the dictionary and pass it in eg:

```
kwargs = {}

# Build the key and add it to the kwargs dict
key = "%s%s" % (q_arg, mode)
kwargs[key] = args[arg]

# Pass kwargs to Q
q = Q(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Please mark the question as answered - to help others searching for this :)